# updating ngrx state using object.assign{}, after state gets updated the page is getting redirect automatically

Tags: angular, ngrx-effects, ngrx-store-4.0

I am adding the user to ngrx state after successful login. Once logged in adding the same user to the state. After updating user details from profile page section and replacing the state using `Object.assign{}`, replaces old state with the new data but after that action the page gets redirect automatically.

I tried every possibility to rectify the code. Page automatically redirects me to my home page. I have not used any `router.navigate('')` anywhere.

I am using: ngrx/store=> v.4.0.4

Below is code for reducer,action and effect:

```
effects.ts

@Effect()
    userUpdate$ = this.actions$
        .ofType(AuthActions.USER_UPDATE)
        .map((action: AuthActions.userUpdate) => action.payload)
        .mergeMap(response => 
          this.authService.retrieveLoggedUser(response.uid, response.token) //will get the user details
            .map(res => {
                var resObj = { user: res };
                return resObj;
            }).switchMap(user =>new UserActions.loadUserUpdate(resObj.user) //returns new action to update the user in state
            )
            .catch((error: any) => {
                return of(new UserActions.loadUserFailure(error));
            })
        );
```

I am able to update the state using `Object.assing{}`, getting the proper value in state but page gets redirected.

Yes I do have auth guards, wheree the profile page is accessed via guards only, so only authenticated users can access their profile page.

There are no errors in the console. The dispatch event executes successfully and updates the state with new data.

my routing.ts looks like below:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomepageComponent, },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
    { path: 'user/updateprofile', component: EditProfileComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'pagenotfound' }
];
```

constructor(private db: Database, private router: Router, private store$: Store, private spinnerService: SpinnerService) {
        this.spinnerService.show();
    }

```
verifyTheUser(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.db.query('user').map(user => user).take(1);
}
```

authGuard.ts

```
 canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.verifyTheUser().map(res => {
            if (res != undefined && res != null && res['user'] != undefined && res['user'] != null) {
                if (res['user'].uid != 0) {
                    this.isLoggedIn = true;
                } else if (res['user'].uid == 0) {
                    this.isLoggedIn = false;
                }
            }
            console.log(this.isLoggedIn);

            return this.isLoggedIn;
        });

    }
```

effect of userUpdate

```
  userUpdate$ = this.actions$
            .ofType(AuthActions.USER_UPDATE)
            .map((action: AuthActions.userUpdate) => action.payload)
            .mergeMap(response => this.authService.retrieveLoggedUser(response.uid, response.token)
                .map(res => {
                   var resObj = { user: {user: res, id: response.id } };
                    return resObj;
                }).switchMap(response =>
                    this.db.insert('user', [response.user])
                        .map(() => new UserActions.loadUserUpdate(response.user))
                )
                .catch((error: any) => {
                   return of(new UserActions.loadUserFailure(error));
                })
            );
```

I am using Observer on saving to get the change detection to reflect it on screen, is because of observer code i am redirected ?? this.profileObserver.next(data);

profilecomponent.ts

```
 UpdateTheProfileInfo(requestData) {
    this.loading = true;
    this.auth.updateInfo(requestData, this.uid).subscribe(() => {
this.UpdateTheUser();
    }, error => {
console.log(error);
    });
  }

  UpdateTheUser() {
    if (this.uid != undefined && this.uid != null && this.keyID != undefined && this.keyID != null) {
      this.store$.dispatch(new AuthActions.userUpdate({ uid: this.uid, token: this.token, id: this.keyID }));
    }
```

Comment: try to provide some more info...are there any errors in console? what does your routing look like? do you have guards?

Comment: Please check the details that i have added ....

Comment: that's wierd. check the template where you fire update action...are you maybe listening for a `(click)` on link where you use˙`<a href="#">` (with hash/pound)? thats the only thing i can think of at the moment that would give such behavior.

Comment: Ok can you help me for handling the <a href="#"> ?.. I have two tabs to activate the tabs i am using <a href="#">.... Also I am submitting the form with the button type="submit"

Comment: so, i am talking under assumption that you use something like `<a href="#"...>` to trigger your update action. if that is the case, remove `href="#"` from your link. technically speaking, you should be actually using a button to trigger your update action because its not a navigation but action that user performs. Additionaly, you could also `return false;` from your `(click)` handler method (if you want to keep using `<a href...>`

Comment: No i am triggering my update using the button of type submit. I am using <a href="#tab1"> to switch the two tabs. Switching the tabs routes me to my pageNotFound component, so i am facing that issue even. where as trigger an update is through only button.

Comment: yes, something is messed up. please show your component code, template for it and section of effects that handle `loadUserUpdate` action

Comment: Also one more wierd behavior I found now is that only first time when i do profile changes and save it redirects me, from second time onwards everything works fine that is second time onwards I am not redirected.

Answer (score 0):

So in the comments you're using a form with button type `submit` to login.

Therefore you have to use the `(submit)` handler binding on your form and your method that gets called by the `submit`- eventhandler hast to prevent the default behavior by using `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: I tried that even too but nothing works for me.... Even I debugged each and every routerLink attribute and programatic navigations i have used. but nothing fires up the navigation issue that i am facing.

Comment: Still the issue is not resolved and I am struggling the navigation redirection

Comment: I have rechecked once again everything and remove the object update effect as posted above that is "AuthActions.USER_UPDATE" completely. Now I am just updating user record and dispatching the action of loading the user. It again behaves in same way that is redirecting the page. As soon I am pushing whole user object in state i.e the state is reset again and the page is getting redirected . Any one know how to solve this????

Comment: Issue is resolved. There was mess in the code execution. Thanks to all giving your time and response. Thanks once again all